# Normal loop doesn't work after custom ones

Tags: php, wordpress

I used two custom loops on my site:

```
<?php $wp_query = new WP_Query("post_type=page&post=15"); while($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
<?php // content ?>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php $wp_query = new WP_Query("post_type=page&post=15"); while($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
<?php // content ?>
<?php $wp_query = new WP_Query('showposts=3&post_type=contests&orderby=meta_value&meta_key=date&order=desc'); if($wp_query->have_posts()) : while($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
<?php //content ?>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); else : ?>
<?php ... ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And then I wanted to return to my regular loop for retrieving the news:

```
<?php rewind_posts(); ?>
<?php while(have_posts()) : <?php // content ?>
<?php endwhile;  ?>
```

But it returns nothing (and there are posts to be displayed). When I tried to run an `if(have_posts...)` statement, it returned `false`. What I did wrong?

Comment: Can you please show rewind_posts and have_posts functions?

Comment: What do you mean? I posted pretty much all of my code.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing nothing wrong per say; WordPress is. Those loop related functions set up and reset globals, making you lose state because you're nesting WP loops. Adding insult to injury, you're overwriting `$wp_query`, which is at the core of the WP loop-related functions.

You could potentially work around these problems in multiple ways. One would be to use output buffers outside of the loop to set a few variables that you can use further down. Another could be to not use the API at all apart from `$q = new WP_Query(...)` and a normal `foreach` loop -- without using the built-in template functions.

(Actually learning php should trump both of these ideas if you don't understand them. Seriously, don't create a WP theme with complicated logic without knowing at least enough php to understand the source code of the template functions you're relying upon.)